# How to transform a SOAP request to a REST request?

Tags: rest, soap, esb, ballerina, wso2-esb

Our customers own a legacy system built on SOAP request/responses. Our API's are defined as REST endpoints.

The API's in Ballerina provide mechanisms to transform a REST request to a SOAP request for a SOAP service. An example is provided [here](https://medium.com/@paulfremantle/transforming-soap-backends-in-ballerina-and-integrating-into-travis-f9774cd06498).

Is there a way in Ballerina to do exact inverse, i.e to transform the SOAP request to a REST request for a REST service ?

Comment: You want SOAP to REST example?

Comment: @PramodyaMendis Yes, please.

Answer (score 0):

This [PR](https://github.com/wso2/ballerina-integrator/pull/214) will help you. It's not yet added to the docs.